# How to Bind Role Middleware inside Controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on Laravel `ACL`, I've created a `Role` Middleware. I've bind the middleware inside my Controller. like this-

`$this->middleware('HasRole:User|Admin|Author')->except(['userEdit','roleEdit']);`

But it's not work properly.every role can access this all methods. if I add in `routes/web.php` then it's works properly.

```
Route::prefix('admin')->middleware(['HasRole:Admin|Author'])->group(function(){
Route::get('/manage-user','AppController@userList')->name('user.list');
Route::get('/manage-role','AppController@roleList')->name('role.list');
});
```

This way `Role` Middleware work properly. **But I want to do this from mycontroller.**

My Controller.

```
 function __construct()
{

  $this->middleware('HasRole:User|Admin|Author')->except(['userEdit','roleEdit','permissionEdit','userUpdate']);
}
```

My Middleware.

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    // return is_array($roles)? $roles: explode('|', $roles);
    $roles=is_array($role)? $roles: explode('|', $role);
    //dd($r);

    if($request->user()===null)
    {
        return response('Insufficient Access',401);
    }

    if($request->user()->hasAnyRole($roles) || !$roles)
    {
         return $next($request);
    }
      return response('Insufficient Permission',401);
    //return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Where did you it in your controller?

Comment: inside my `class constructor`

Comment: can you add your `HasRole` middleware code ?

Comment: @rkj middleware code added, please see.

Comment: fix this line  `$roles=is_array($role)? $roles: explode('|', $role);` with     `$roles=is_array($role)? $role: explode('|', $role);` but that doesn't make any difference

Comment: tried this, doesn't make any difference. @rkj

Comment: try removing  `|| !$roles` condition

Comment: remove `||!$roles` && check it's not working.

Comment: can you dd ($roles) next the line is_array

Comment: What version of Laravel?

Comment: Are you saying that if you use the middleware in the `constructor` the excluded methods also get protected for a non-permitted user? The excluded methods shouldn't be protected. Is that it?

Comment: yes, that's it.

Comment: Is it intentional that you have `User|Admin|Author` in your constructor but only `Admin|Author` in your routes?